# Can not start Chrome via command line

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I have a script that needs to run on multiple machines.

The problem is, if I open a command line and type in `chrome` or `chrome.exe`, I get the same error message that it is not recognized as an internal or external command...

I have already added it to my paths (as per screen shot below, see bottom entry in the paths) .

It works this way on other computers.

[image]

The command prompt has been restarted (as has the computer) since updating the paths.

Why does it not open Chrome as it does on my other machine(s)?

Whilst entering `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` directly into the command line and pressing enter does make Chrome launch, I don't see why the path is not working.

Comment: Did you open a new command prompt after adding it to path?

Comment: It has been like this for a while to be honest. To answer you, yes. I know that the command prompt reads the variables at start up and so any changes made after won't have any affect on the command prompt until it restarts. Thanks for checking

Comment: Generally you just add the folder path that contains the executable into path and not specifically name the executable itself. Although I tested it on my own machine with both ways and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @n8te that's it!! I'd put the entire path in... Can you move this to an answer

Comment: Oh nice. About to leave work so don't have time to post an answer. But feel free to self answer.

Comment: @n8te are you able to post?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Added answer but now it's just a duplicate of the other answer :/

Comment: If you use the run... box then you can directly type `chrome` and run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you had the folder path *and* executable listed in your path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

You should omit `chrome.exe` and just put the folder path that `chrome.exe` is located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Comment: I realize this is just a duplicate of the other answer, but OP was waiting on me to provide an answer based on a previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The entry in the PATH is invalid:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

It should only contain the folder, not the program:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Comment: +1, but I don't feel I can mark as such due to the comments (waiting for @n8te to post the answer)

Answer (score 1):

For the new 64bit version, the path has become

`C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`